# BroadcastReceiver onReceive called 3 times instead of one

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

I send a broadcast after i get a push `notification` within my `onMessageReceived()` method.

in BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive()` method I want to display an `AlertDialog` that allows the user to move to another fragment.

The problem is that my `onReceive()` method is called 3 times, instead of 1 and my `AlertDialog` opens 3 times.

I tried something like:

```
private int onReceiveCalledIndex = 0;

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getExtras() != null)
        {
            String requestIdString = (String) intent.getExtras().get(Constants.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CHAT_PUT_EXTRA);
            Log.e("DEBUG_RECEIVE",String.valueOf(onReceiveCalledIndex));
            onReceiveCalledIndex += 1;
            if(onReceiveCalledIndex == 2 ) showNewMessageDialog(requestIdString);
        }
    }
```

But I get these logs and my index is never incremented.It's like the method is called on three different threads simultaneously ...

> E/DEBUG_RECEIVE: 0
>
> E/DEBUG_RECEIVE: 0
>
> E/DEBUG_RECEIVE: 0

Someone please tell me a way to make the `onReceive()` to be called just once or to handle so I will open only one dialog.

Comment: Make sure you are registering broadcast receiver only once.

Comment: its better to register BroadcastReceiver in your activity's onResume and unRegister it in onDestroy

Comment: can you post snippet of your onMessageReceived() ?

Answer (score 1):

Register and Unregister broadcast receiver dynamically

To register use:-

```
this.registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(droid.intent.action.TIME_TICK'));
```

To unregister:-

```
this.unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams that if you register the receiver from within the activity instead of the fragment all works just fine.

Thanks for help.